# Comparing c.loc[index, 'MAX'] which is an integer, with an integer is returning an error

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am checking which pop years have the biggest difference between them. Here is the code. It cannot compare r and c.loc[index, 'MAX'], why is that happening? They both should be integers...

```
        c = census_df[['COUNTY','POPESTIMATE2010', 'POPESTIMATE2011', 'POPESTIMATE2012', 'POPESTIMATE2013', 'POPESTIMATE2014', 'POPESTIMATE2015']]
c['MAX'] = 0 #this is where the biggest difference for each county is stored
for index, row in c.iterrows():
        x = 5
        y = x - 1
        while x >= 1: #check how you do the ops
            while y >= 0:
                r = abs(row['POPESTIMATE201'+str(x)] - row['POPESTIMATE201'+str(y)])
                if r > row['MAX']:
                    c.loc[index, ['MAX']] = r
                y -= 1
            x -= 1
c.sort_values(by=['MAX'], ascending= False)
return c.iloc[1, ['COUNTY']]
```

here are the sample dataframe and output needed,
Dataframe :

```
      COUNTY  POPESTIMATE2010       ...         POPESTIMATE2014  POPESTIMATE2015
```

0          0          4785161       ...                 4846411          4858979
1          1            54660       ...                   55290            55347
2          3           183193       ...                  199713           203709
3          5            27341       ...                   26815            26489
4          7            22861       ...                   22549            22583
5          9            57373       ...                   57658            57673
6         11            10887       ...                   10829            10696
7         13            20944       ...                   20276            20154

OUTPUT NEEDED:

The County name with the highest delta between the 2 of its popestimate years as a string. example: 'Barbour County'

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe, as well as a desired output? There is a much better way to do this than iterrows.

Comment: Use `census_df.pct_change()` or `.diff()` and check this difference :)

Comment: What does these do? and where should I apply them?